# Clearing operation in costmap_2d explanation?

Tags: ros, navigation, clear-costmap, costmap-2d, costmap-2d-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone explain the following sentence or with an image maybe ?

A clearing operation, however, consists of raytracing through a grid from the origin of the sensor outwards for each observation reported.

Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190866/clearing-operation-in-costmap_2d-explanation-?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sensor data gives you two things: Where an obstacle is and where an obstacle isn't. Imagine you have a single laser that starts at point A encounters an obstacle at point B.

The marking operation is putting a lethal value in the costmap at point B.

The clearing operation is taking all the points between A and B and marking them as free space.

The process of finding the line is often referred to as ray tracing, and is explained here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4